# Copy select query result to csv in postgres

Tags: postgresql, csv

I have following script that I am using to copy select query result in csv file.

```
psql -h hostname -U username -d dbname -t -A -F"," --c "some query with multiple joins and conditions" > "E:\output.csv"
```

while executing the script it is creating the file with name `output.csv` but there is no data in file.

I have tried with sample query simple join operation with 3 tables for limited data and it is working fine.

But with actual query it keeps executing for the couple of hours and ended with the empty file. Which is dissatisfying to get empty file after waiting such a long period.

any suggestions or corrections?

Comment: I know this is the "Is your computer plugged in?" question but... does your really big SQL statement produce results when run manually? If it's running for hours, perhaps it's running out of memory or space and dying before writing out to the file?

Comment: What do you mean by sample query ? Is sample query present on same server where your actual data reside or it is different ?

Comment: sample query means, I run a query which returns 2-3 records. I am running both the queries on the same server and data is also there on the same server.